# How to filter data from table with date in descending order using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch all data from table as per date field in descending order using PHP and Mysql. I am explaining my table below.

#### db_special:

```
id          name         date

1            Ram          12/04/2017 15:31:57 PM

2            Raj          12/03/2017 05:31:57 AM

3            Rahul        11/28/2017 12:30:54 PM
```

Here is my query:

```
select * 
from db_special 
where
    STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Here I implemented one logic to fetch last 7 days data and now I need to implement sorting as per the same date field in descending order using `MySQL and PHP`.

Comment: you cannot simply use order by ? Maybe I didn't get your question. date is varchar ?

Comment: Actually I was sorting after fetching the data first using `usort` but it is throwing error.

Comment: @farbiondriven : its `varchar` need to convert.

Comment: If you have chance to change the db and convert to datetime it's much better. Did you try to put ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(table_date, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC in the query ?

Comment: I did but its only sorting by date not with time and AM/PM. I need both.

Comment: so try to use `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(table_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') DESC`

Comment: No,same result its not sorting as per expected.

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko : I have format like this `date('m/d/Y H:i:s A')`.

Comment: try use this format when convert string to date

Comment: No it is not sorting as per expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using a VARCHAR/CHAR/CLOB field to store a date? That is very bad. It makes kittens cry. Please don't do it.

> using PHP and Mysql

No. you don't retrieve data from a DBMS then sort it in PHP. That too is very bad (unless you're Facebook, in which case it is possibly a bit silly, but that is another story). You sort in the database.

Just add an [ORDER BY clause](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_orderby.asp) at the end of your SELECT